# Inkscape: How to make rounded corners on a object already clipped?

Tags: inkscape

Here the svg, You can play with it to have a better feel of my situation: https://gofile.io/?c=WqJbII

here an image of the situation:
[image]

I am trying to make rounded corners on an already clipped's object in Inkscape. Fact is that I don't succeed to make the two object - the clipped-circle in green and curved line in yellow on the image- bound together to release a round corner.

I have tried to clip the curved line above the clipped-circle but it seems the curved-line absorbs the whole circle when I would it just cut the corner to round the corner. I have played a bit with the path's functions, with failing to reach my objectives so far.

thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how clipping works. A clipping path needs to be a single path, or a compound path.

If you want to do it using a clipping mask, instead draw a simple shape with curves using the Bézier tool, then apply that as the clipping mask.

Example:  Result of applying clipping path shown right

[image]

Another completely different method is not to use a clipping path at all.  When drawing with the Ellipse tool, you can use the "Switch to Arc" option in the Tool Controls along the top, and in the Stroke Style tab you can select the "Round Cap" option.

[image]